# Xcode 9.2 cannot connect git server through proxy

Tags: xcode, git, proxy

In my company, we have a git server on intranet. We should connect it through a proxy. However I cannot achieve this on Xcode 9.

Proxy is set on Network preferences, ~/.curlrc, ~/.gitconfig, ~/.bash_profile, /etc/gitconfig, /etc/profile. Xcode does not respect any of them.

While trying to clone a repo in Xcode it shows this error:

```
curl error: Could not resolve host: myintranetdomain (-1)
```

I can clone the repository onterminal (after setting ~/.bash_profile). Xcode cannot pull, push, on this repo.

What can we do to connect git server through proxy with Xcode?

P.S. Xcode 8.2.1 respects the proxy setting in ~/.gitconfig

Comment: Did you find a solution? (p.s: I can pull, but i can't push while i can do both in terminal)

Comment: try Proxifier for mac

Comment: It's still a problem in Xcode 13 (beta 4). Please tell Apple to fix it - should be relatively simple: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5008610828484608